# Jenkins with continuous integration

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, hudson

How can I create a build queue that conatins of 2 consecutice jobs using Jenkins?

The first should be automatically triggered if developer checks in new code in `svn`. I can already achieve this part by polling `SCM` every minute.

Now, after a successful build I want to trigger a second job with `Webdriver` automation functional scripts.

Comment: Sorry. Thats what i meant. Checkin  not Checkout. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @put on hold: The author of the question seems to know already which tools to use (SVN, Jenkins, Selenium). She doesn't ask for a book etc. either.

Comment: I edited the question. It should be alright now.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have two questions: 1) how to trigger a job on subversion checkin and 2) how to have one job trigger a second job when the first job completes.

You configure the triggering of the first job in the "Build Triggers" section by checking the "Poll SCM" item and entering a scheduled like "*/5 * * * *". You will also need to configure your connection to subversion in the "Source Code Management" section.

You configure the triggering of the second job in the "Post Build Actions" section of the first job. In particular, you will choose "Build other projects" and enter the name of the second job.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I am able to do the first part. I will try the 2nd part.